# Are multiple XML default namespaces allowed?

Tags: xml, soap, namespaces

Consider the following xml

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns="mycompany.com.myservice">
<soap:Header>
<To xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://mycompany.com/myservice</To>
<Action xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">mycompany.com/myservice/dosomething</Action>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<mypayload>hello world</mypayload>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

is the use of multiple un-aliased default namespaces valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The case where you have multiple default namespaces is covered in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> The scope of a default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, **excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations**.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an example?

Comment: @barrypicker — The code in the question is an example. `<To>` and all its child nodes are in a different namespace to `<Envelope>`.

Comment: Isn't `<To>` child of `<soap:Envelope>` and so above text " excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations." is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

(that's all I was going to say but StackOverflow doesn't like short answers).